# How convert a number from base 10 to base 10 in C?

Tags: c

I have been writing a program to print an input integer in base 10. I have to use 'putchar(int c)' to display digits and a negative sign.

Essentially, I have to take the input integer, extract the digits from it using modulo, and reverse these digits and reprint them. I have to declare an array of characters to store the digits and then go through the array backwards to print the final output.

This program should read an integer, use putchar(int c) to dispay the digits, and exit.

I have the following code, except I cannot figure what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int x;
    int k;
    int y;
    char digits[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    char A[k];

    while (x != 0) {
        y = x % 10;

        A[k++] = digits[y];

        putchar(digits[y]);

        x = x / 10;
    }

    printf("%i\n", y);

    for (; k >= 0; --k) {
        putchar(A[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong, because this program does compile.

Comment: So what's wrong with it? And what's your question? ("how to convert from base 10 to base 10" doesn't seem to be worded very well - you don't have to do anything to convert a number from a base to the same base!)

Comment: `x` is being used uninitialised.

Comment: You never assign `x` a value. This causes undefined behavior on the lines `while (x != 0)` and `x = x / 10`

Comment: @kaylum Bet me to it ;)

Comment: And `k` also being used uninitialised. If you need further help, fix those obvious problems. Then describe your requirements better. "Converting from base 10 to base 10" isn't exactly clear. Word that better. Including describing the input, expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `x`, `k` or `y`. This means that they could potentially contain any value. To fix this, you should give those variables a value:

```
int x = 0;
int k = 0;
int y = 0;
```

But from the looks of it, `x` is the input to your algorithm, so you need to read input from somewhere

**Nitpicking**

Instead of using `x = x / 10`, it is much cleaner and concise to use the `/=` operator:

```
x /= 10;
```

Comment: Slight correction. `y` is not initialised but is correctly set before use already: `y = x % 10;`.

Comment: Nope, scratch that. `y` does need to be initialised as it may not enter the `while` block (though technically only used in a debug `printf` in that case).